# Is there are better way to assign a variable a value when the like condition is met?

Tags: sql, stored-functions

So I'll have table values where some values in a column will have a 4 digit value and if they exist, I have to add the 3rd value to a variable. So if I have 1234, the variable Number will be 3. Below is what I came up with. It does the job but I don't like the solution. Is there a better way to do this?

```
SET @Number = CASE
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]0[0-9]%' THEN '0'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]1[0-9]%' THEN '1'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]2[0-9]%' THEN '2'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]3[0-9]%' THEN '3'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]4[0-9]%' THEN '4'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]5[0-9]%' THEN '5'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]6[0-9]%' THEN '6'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]7[0-9]%' THEN '7'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]8[0-9]%' THEN '8'
                      WHEN @Name LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]9[0-9]%' THEN '9'
                      ELSE '<#>'
                  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @Number = SUBSTRING ( @Name,3 , 1 )
```

Should do the trick for you!

EDIT:

As the 4 digit number can be anywhere in your string, try:

```
SELECT IIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @name) <> 0
       , SUBSTRING(@name, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @name) + 2, 1)
       , '#')
```

The patindex tells you where your pattern starts, so we can use that to home in on the string, and the iif lets you handle the #.

If you have a 5 number before your 4 digit one it'll be wrong, but its the same bug as you'd have in your case solution

Comment: There's no exact spot within the data where the 4 digit number will be, just that some of them may have it. Is there a way to pinpoint where in the substring the 3rd of the 4 digit number will be?

Comment: Ah. Updated to account for the random place of the 4 digits in the string